# PHP Processing SScript Not Picking Up Image

Tags: php, html

I'm very novice with PHP so please excuse the such elementrary question.

I'm working on a form for my site which has several text inputs but now I'm working on implementing an image upload functionality but I'm having troubles with getting off the ground floor.

In my form I have:

```
<form id="generalform" class="container" method="POST"  action="process.php" autocomplete="on" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

<several text inputs here that work>

<input type="file" class="fileuploadinput" name="Image1">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

but my script:

```
if(!empty($_POST['Image1'])) {  
                    echo 'File Selected and Data set in DB';
                    } else {
                        echo 'NO File Selcted but Data Inserted';                   

                    }
```

ALWAYS echo's NO File Selcted but Data Inserted and it DOES insert the text data into the DB but why isn't it picking up the image and instead telling me no image is selected (via my error msg "'NO File Selcted but Data Inserted")??

If anyone could help me with this I'd be most appreciative and I thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your uploaded files won't be accessible via the $_POST superglobal. They will be accessible via the [$_FILES superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php).

This should work:

```
if(file_exists($_FILES['Image1']['tmp_name']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['Image1']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo 'File Selected and Data set in DB';
} 
else {
    echo 'NO File Selcted but Data Inserted';                   
}
```

[file_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) checks to see if the file exists and [is_uploaded_file()](http://www.php.net/is_uploaded_file) checks to see if the file in question was uploaded via HTTP POST (in this case, your form).

I'm a bit confused about your output. What do you mean by:

> NO File Selcted but Data Inserted

Comment: Hi @Wayne Whitty, Thanks so much for your help. I'll be taking all of this  in but I'm sure I'll have more questions as once I get my head around this, I've got a load of code I'm gonna (try to) drop in place of the first echo statement. (wish me luck plz). BTW,  The guy I got this classifieds left me a mess of poorly written code (full of html errors too), now I'm trying to whittle through it and make sense of it while also making the classifieds much more user friendly and I appreciate all of your guy's help!!

Comment: Hi @Wayne Whitty, The output is just a visual aid for me so I can get an idea of what's happening within the script. This output will  be getting replaced with other code eventually. As the matter of fact I'm really struggling with what & how to do what I'm trying to accomplish. If you wouldn't mind corresponding with me via email I'd sure appreciate  it as I'd like to send over a couple files for you to see, this way I can field a few questions off of the code you'll be able to see. If interested, please PM me an email and I'll get the code over to you.